# Trying to remove part of a string using a dynamic range but loop won't stop running

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic

As the title suggest I have a dynamic range where each cell contains "XXXX-XXXXX-####" and the code I have (atm) removes the "XXXX-XXXXX" part with a dynamic range but won't stop running once it reaches the last cell.

```
Sub removestring()
    'To Find The Last Row
    Dim LRow As Double
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim x As Variant
    x = LastRow
'To Remove "XXXX-XXXXXX-"
row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
    the_description = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number)
    the_description = Replace(the_description, "XXXX-XXXXXX-", " ")
    Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number) = the_description

Loop Until row_number = LastRow
'Can't Get Loop To Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: Toss a break in, check the value of LastRow before you enter your loop.  If LastRow is 0 or less it will never be equal to row_number.

Comment: I'm incredibly new to VBA- would you be able to expand a little on as to how I can check the value of LastRow ?

Comment: @JosephC I got it now- thank you! :)

Comment: Add a [break point](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm) then mouse over the text in your code for LastRow.  It should tell you what the value is.  My guess is you have no data in Column A, and therefore the last row is 0.  Changing the line to `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` will probably work.. but check your values with breakpoints :)

Comment: You declare `LRow As Double` but after that you are using `LastRow`. Make sure to properly declare all of your variables. A row can be declared as `Ìnteger` as it don't have decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is best practise to declare all variables.

I changed the Do-Loop to a for-loop. Both is working but as you know the end of the loop (LastRow) I think a for loop is the better choice in this case.

Make sure to look for the last row in the right column.

```
Sub removestring()
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim row_number As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim the_description As String

    Set wks = Sheets(1) 'Refer to sheet number
    'Set wks=ActiveSheet 'Refer to active sheet
    'Set wks=Sheets("Name of the sheet") 'Refer to named sheet

    LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    'Are you sure you are searching the last row in column A? 
    'Below you are referring to column E.


    'To Remove "XXXX-XXXXXX-"

    For row_number = 1 To LastRow
        DoEvents
        the_description = wks.Range("E" & row_number)
        the_description = Replace(the_description, "XXXX-XXXXXX-", " ")
        wks.Range("E" & row_number) = the_description
    Next row_number

End Sub
```